# How do you install a module in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I know how to import modules however I don't know how to get a module from the internet.

Comment: You should use `pip`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the module. Most times the easiest way is to use `pip install <module>` in the cmd. Another option is downloading the module and if it has a `setup.py` file in it, do `python setup.py install` from within the module's directory.

Comment: Which module do you want to install? You need its name and then just write the command in the cmd

Comment: I've tried installing `numpy` but it says `install` is invalid syntax

Comment: I have Python 3.4 (I also have Python 2.7 but I wasn't using it) with IDLE. In the Python 3.4 folder in the start bar I selected the Python 3.4 command line. I then typed `pip install numpy` and nothing else

Comment: You should write the command in the cmd, not in the python command line. To open the cmd using the keyboard press winkey+r and then type cmd and press enter. Alternatively, click the start button, type "cmd" and open the program, It should look like a black console.

Comment: It says `'pip' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

Comment: See how to install pip: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows

Comment: I reinstalled `pip` and tried it again but it still has the same error

Comment: You added it to the path as the instructions say? If so, you can ask a new question since you have a different problem now